# Why bind only first attribute?

Tags: opengl, c++

I'm create OpenGL renderer, but when I bind vertex attributes I can attribute only first attributes. Where I got error?
My code:

```
Mesh::Mesh(Shader &shader, int size, GLuint *indices) {
    shaderProgram = &shader;
    _meshLenght = size;

    glGenBuffers(1, &_ebo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _ebo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices)* sizeof(GLuint), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

void Mesh::AddDataPointer(GLchar *name, const GLvoid *data, GLenum type, GLint size) {
    GLint variableLocation = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram->GetProgram(), name);
    if (variableLocation == -1) {
        std::cerr << "Variable does not exist, or it name began with prefix gl!" << std::endl;
        return;
    }


    GLuint vBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(data)*sizeof(GLvoid*), data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    GLuint vertexArray;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertexArray);
    glBindVertexArray(vertexArray);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray((GLuint) variableLocation);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer((GLuint) variableLocation, size, type, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid *) 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    VertexData vertexData = {
            vertexArray,
            data,
            type};
    _variables.insert(_variables.end(), vertexData);
}

void Mesh::Draw() {
    for (auto const& value : _variables) {
        glBindVertexArray(value.location);
    }
    if (_ebo==0)
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, _meshLenght);
    else {
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _ebo);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, _meshLenght, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    }
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

Comment: This question could be improved with a more detailed explanation of *what you're trying to do*. For example, by adding comments to the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using `vertexArray` correctly. There should only be 1 per object

```
Mesh::Mesh(Shader &shader, int size, GLuint *indices) {
    shaderProgram = &shader;
    _meshLenght = size;

    //create one here
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &_vao);
    glBindVertexArray(_vao);

    glGenBuffers(1, &_ebo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _ebo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices)* sizeof(GLuint), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    //vao also stored the GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER binding

    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

void Mesh::AddDataPointer(GLchar *name, const GLvoid *data, GLenum type, GLint size) {
    GLint variableLocation = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram->GetProgram(), name);
    if (variableLocation == -1) {
        std::cerr << "Variable does not exist, or it name began with prefix gl!" << std::endl;
        return;
    }


    GLuint vBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(data)*sizeof(GLvoid*), data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    //bind here
    glBindVertexArray(_vao);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray((GLuint) variableLocation);
    glVertexAttribPointer((GLuint) variableLocation, size, type, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid *) 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);//unbind

    VertexData vertexData = {
            vBuffer,
            data,
            type};
    _variables.insert(_variables.end(), vertexData);
}

void Mesh::Draw() {
    glBindVertexArray(_vao); //bind again for draw

    if (_ebo==0)
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, _meshLenght);
    else {
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, _meshLenght, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    }
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```